# how to get the content of a title using BeautifulSoup4 and requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So i have taken the title of the medicines from this link : [Medicines List](https://www.klikdokter.com/obat)

now i want to get the content for every medicines meanwhile every medicines has it owns link
Example :
[Medicines Example](https://www.klikdokter.com/obat/abajos)

how can I get the content of that medicines using BeautifulSoup4 and requests library?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    title = [x.text for x in soup.select(
        'a[class$=section__item-link]')]
    count = 0
    for x in range (0, len(title)):
        count += 1
        print("{0}. {1}\n".format(count, title[x]))


main('https://www.klikdokter.com/obat')
```

Comment: Get a `href`s from the links you've found with `soup.select` and request their pages separately with a new get request for each

Comment: so if there is 500 different medicines I need to request for each medicine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can see as the response from https://www.klikdokter.com/obat you should be able to do something like this:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'
BASEURL = 'https://www.klikdokter.com/obat'
headers = {'User-Agent': AGENT}
response = requests.get(BASEURL, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='topics-index--section__item-link'):
    href = tag.get('href')
    if href is not None:
        print(href)
        response = requests.get(href, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        """ Do your processing here """
```

Comment: okay so this showing only the link of each medicines, if I want to take the content of the medicines like the description of the medicines, how am I supposed to do?

Comment: You'll need to process the response data from each of the URLs that my code prints

Comment: so i need to do requests for each sites? can you do an example for me? cause I'm new to this

Comment: Yes you do and that's exactly what my code demonstrates. You already know how to parse the HTML response from the main site so it's just a matter of doing the same kind of thing with the subsequent requests. It's all going to depend on what you want to extract